# PHP Hex Code read as Hex strings when encoding to base64

Tags: php, base64, hex

I have an array of hex code in this format

```
FF8FFE00+++++
```

The above example is just one string, with + representing the rest of the over 60k long hex code (no use in hogging your broswer). The format looks exactly like that. So let's say

```
$a = 'FFD8FF++++ string';
echo base64_encode($a);
```

When printing the above, it takes the hex code as a string and generates the base64 out of the string instead of the hexdec

Looked all over, but it just seems that there are either conversions that make the hex code get hex encoded as well.

In NPP+ i converted a the string to ASCII then encoded in base64 and the result was the expected one (base64 that i can use for an image).

Any idea how I can tell php that the string is actually hex node, not a string?

Comment: you need to convert the hex string into a byte array first and then base64 encode it. I not a PHP expert, but maybe you find something [with a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5Dhex+to+byte+)

Comment: I did not clearly understand what you are trying to do. But have a look at transcoding functions [hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin) and base64_encode() that.

Comment: That did the trick. Made an array with all 1000+ strings, made a foreach,  `$base = base64_encode(hex2bin($key));`, and the made the output with `<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,$base'>" ` All went went perfect. You can put in the answer so I can mark is as correct, and I`ll do a full edit on the question.

Comment: @MarkusZeller you're invited to write an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

With [hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin) you can transform a string containing hexadecimals into binary data (stored as a string in PHP). After that encode the binary string to base64 format.

```php
$hex = 'FFD8FF';            // and much more hex values as string as in your example
$bin = hex2bin($hex);       // convert the hex values to binary data stored as a PHP string
$b64 = base64_encode($bin); // this contains the base64 representation of the binary data
```

> string(4) "/9j/"